# Handle different kinds of return values in a single decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a Python class with several class methods which some of them return a single `value` and the others return `(value1, value2)`. They should return `None`/`(None, None)` for some errors at the beginning of these methods, for example:

```
class Demo:
    def foo(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
        if not self._db.is_connected():
            return None
        # do something
        return x

    def bar(*args, **kwargs) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        if not self._db.is_connected():
            return (None, None)
        # do something
        return (x, y)
```

I try to use a decorator for this check. I know this works:

```
class Demo:
    def _is_connected_decorator(func):
        def magic(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return func(self, *args, is_connected=self._db.is_connected(), **kwargs)
        return magic

    @_is_connected_decorator
    def foo(*args, is_connected=False, **kwargs) -> int:
        if not is_connected:
            return None
        # do something
        return x

    @_is_connected_decorator
    def bar(*args, is_connected=False, **kwargs) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        if not is_connected:
            return (None, None)
        # do something
        return (x, y)
```

However, I want totally put the check into a single decorator without modifying the args or return values of foo() and bar() like this:

```
class Demo:
    def _is_connected_decorator(func):
        def magic(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self._db.is_connected():
                return None   # error return
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return magic

    @_is_connected_decorator
    def foo(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
        # do something
        return x

    @_is_connected_decorator
    def bar(*args, **kwargs) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        # do something
        return (x, y)
```

However, the decorator does not know it should return `None` or `(None, None)`. Is there a good way to handle both kinds of return values?

Comment: It seems to me that raising an exception would be a better approach to it. Then it would be consistent for all methods and explicit in its error.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych It seems that changing to exception is equal to modifying the return value, where this should change the logic of the caller. How to change the framework from return value to exception without modify the caller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe specify the default value?

```
class Demo:
    def _is_connected_decorator(default):
        def decorator(func):
            def magic(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if not self._db.is_connected():
                    return default
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return magic
        return decorator

    @_is_connected_decorator(None)
    def foo(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
        # do something
        return x

    @_is_connected_decorator((None, None))
    def bar(*args, **kwargs) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        # do something
        return (x, y)
```

[Demo at repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AttentiveCompetentInterchangeability#main.py) using this test:

```
x, y = 1, 2
d = Demo()
d._db = type('', (), {})
d._db.is_connected = lambda: connected
for connected in False, True:
    print(d.foo())
    print(d.bar())
```

Output:

```
None
(None, None)
1
(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems a clear concept to handle this problem, and can be easily extended to more different default/error return values.